# How to remove any html tags within a specific pattern in beautifulsoup

Tags: html, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

```html
<p>
 A 
 <span>die</span> 
  is thrown \(x = {-b \pm 
  <span>\sqrt</span>
  {b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\) twice. What is the probability of getting a sum 7 from
both the throws?
</p>
```

In above html I need to remove only the tags within "\(tags\)" i.e  `\(x = {-b \pm <span>\sqrt</span> {b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\\)`.
I have just started with beautifulsoup is there any way this can be achieved with beautifulsoup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with the solution to my question. Hope it helps others. Feel free to give me suggestion to improve the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
html = """<p>
     A 
     <span>die</span> 
      is thrown \(x = {-b \pm 
      <span>\sqrt</span>
      {b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\) twice. What is the probability of getting a sum 7 from
    both the throws?
    </p> <p> Test </p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
mathml_start_regex = re.compile(r'\\\(')
mathml_end_regex = re.compile(r'\\\)')

for p_tags in soup.find_all('p'):
    match = 0 #Flag set to 1 if '\(' is found and again set back to 0 if '\)' is found.
    for p_child in p_tags.children:
        try: #Captures Tags that contains \(
            if re.findall(mathml_start_regex, p_child.text):
                match += 1
        except: #Captures NavigableString that contains \(
            if re.findall(mathml_start_regex, p_child):
                match += 1
        try: #Replaces Tag with Tag's text
            if match == 1:
                p_child.replace_with(p_child.text)
        except: #No point in replacing NavigableString since they are just strings without Tags
            pass
        try: #Captures Tags that contains \)
            if re.findall(mathml_end_regex, p_child.text):
                match = 0
        except: #Captures NavigableString that contains \)
            if re.findall(mathml_end_regex, p_child):
                match = 0
```

Output:

```
<p>
     A 
     <span>die</span> 
      is thrown \(x = {-b \pm 
      \sqrt
      {b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\) twice. What is the probability of getting a sum 7 from
    both the throws?
    </p>
<p> Test
</p>
```

In the above code I searched all 'p' tag and it returns *bs4.element.ResultSet*. In the first for loop I am iterating to the result set to get individual 'p' tags and in the second for loop and using the .*children* generator to iterate through the 'p' tags children (contains both navigable string and tags). Each 'p' tag's child is searched for the '\(', if found the match is set to 1 and if when iterating to the children that match is 1 then the tags in the particular child is removed using *replace_with* and finally the match is set to zero when '\)' is found.

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful soup alone can't get a substring. You can use regex along with it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """<p>
     A 
     <span>die</span> 
      is thrown \(x = {-b \pm 
      <span>\sqrt</span>
      {b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\) twice. What is the probability of getting a sum 7 from
    both the throws?
    </p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print re.findall(r'\\\(.*?\)', soup.text, re.DOTALL)
```

Output:

```
[u'\\(x = {-b \\pm \n  \\sqrt\n  {b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}\\)']
```

Regex:

```
\\\(.*?\) - Get substring from ( to ).
```

If you want to strip the newlines and whitespaces, you can do it like so:

```
res = re.findall(r'\\\(.*?\)', soup.text, re.DOTALL)[0]
print ' '.join(res.split())
```

Output:

```
\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt {b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)
```

HTML wrappers around the string:

```
print BeautifulSoup(' '.join(res.split()))
```

Output:

```
<html><body><p>\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt {b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</p></body></html>
```

Comment: Hi I expected the output to be [u'\\(x = {-b \\pm \n  \\sqrt\n  {b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}\\)']. Can you suggest changes in regex?

Comment: @waranlogesh Sure. Include the backslash also before `(`. Modified the solution.

Comment: is there a way to save the printed changes back to html?

Comment: @waranlogesh What do you mean? The html is already giving this output: `A die is thrown \(x = {-b \pm \sqrt {b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\) twice. What is the probability of getting a sum 7 from both the throws?`

Comment: I mean when i give print(soup.prettify()) am getting the original html without the changes.

Comment: @waranlogesh Try this: `print ' '.join(soup.text.split())`

Comment: @ MYGz I want to remove only the tags inside  "\(tags\)" and the changes need to reflected in soup object so that I can do further processing with the modified html content.